# Bootstrap column with two fullwidth block buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a Bootstrap column to resize buttons nicely when the screen type changes. But the buttons end up with no space between them and and two separate lines (on the small screen).

How do I get them to resize into smaller buttons, and not split onto a new line?

[image: want this...]
[image: get this (on a smaller screen)]

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Example!</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-4">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block" role="button">Add Item</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" role="button">Remove Item</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the same styling for small devices as well as large devices, you can omit the `md` styling and just use `sm`. If the width get's *really* small, you can remove the `offset` and use that gained width on the elements instead on `xs` widths.

To fix the buttons being cut off, remove the `btn-block` class.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mosed3sL/1)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Add Item</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Remove Item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As a side note, if you want the buttons to be centered here, use `offset` 3 instead of 4.

Comment: Okay, try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mosed3sL/2/). I have already addressed the buttons being cut.

Comment: @MatthewMalone, if this solved your problem, please mark it as "Accepted".

Answer (score 1):

If i am clear then try my updated code.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Add Item</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Remove Item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `col-xs-3` instead of `col-md-3` and `col-xs-offset-4` instead of `col-md-offset-4`

Comment: You asked how to get buttons to resize smaller and not split onto a new line and that seems to do the trick. What do you mean by cut off?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that bootstrap grid row is of 12 column, so what ever offset or column you are using it should add up to 12 and to target small screen devices such as mobile use `col-xs-*`. Everything else is fine.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block" role="button">Add Item</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" role="button">Remove Item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```